# Why my edit button works only once even I use $('[isEditButton="true"]').on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code, and I has been really frustrating on identifying the problem.

I tried to use

```
$('[isEditButton="true"]').on('click', function(){ codes })
or 
$('table tr td').on('click', '[isEditButton="true"]' , function(){ codes })
```

but both yield unexpected result, the edit button can only be clicked once.

I searched the Jquery doc and used the so-called [Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/), however, still did not work, the edit button is clicked once, also the newly injected button cannot be automatically attached the click event.

My online code

http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/mAjmU/2/

Anyone can give me some pointers on what is going on. I am really crazy on this problem. Thanks in advance for any kind helpers! Really need you guys!

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine for me on Chrome, can you tell what exactly is not working for you in your fiddle?

Comment: You may want to know that using a class name is often a lot, lot faster for selectors than a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `[isEditButton]` elements are being dynamically appended, so you need to use `on` with a delegate handler, with that parent selector being available on DOM load. Your second example nearly fixed the problem, except the `table tr td` elements are being dynamically appended too. Try this:

```
$('#address_list').on('click', '[isEditButton="true"]', function() {
     // rest of your code...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mAjmU/5/)

Comment: Thank you Rory! This is the solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did this

`$(document).on('click', '[isEditButton="true"]', function() {})`

Seemed to work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/mAjmU/6/

Comment: While this will work, this is exactly what `live()` used to do, and why it was deprecated. You should attach to the closest available parent element, not the `document`.

Comment: Thank you Kolby! Your code works too! But I can only give one correct answer, which I gave to Rory this time. But thanks again Kolby!

Answer (score -2):

why don't you use this

```
if (isset($_POST['isEditButton'])){
    //do some codes 
}
else{
    //do this
}
```

Comment: Because that's PHP and the OP is using javascript?